# Elasticsearch upgrade order based on node roles

Tags: elasticsearch, upgrade, roles

I looked for this in many websites, including Elastic official documentation, without success.

I have one Elasticsearch cluster with:

- 3 Master nodes
- 4 Data nodes
- 4 Ingest nodes
- 2 Client nodes

I must perform a rolling upgrade (from 5.x to 5.x) but the official docs do not explain the order based on node roles.

Should I upgrade Master nodes at first? What next? Data nodes?

I mean, I need to know which is the best way to get the whole cluster upgraded.

Thanks,
Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a similar situation and elastic recommended upgrading master first, followed by data and then client nodes.

It's worth checking if your 5.x version has an upgrade assistant available (You see that in Kibana).

Comment: Could you share with me the link to the ElasticSearch's recommendation you mention?